# Why is Greninja Ash's only bonded Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon

If Ash bonded with his Greninja that he had for one generation, but he won't use it anymore, why haven't Pokémon like Pikachu or Tauros bond with Ash instead?

Answer (score 1):

In the same way that not every pokemon has a [Mega Evolution](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mega_Evolution) the only pokemon known to have the bond ability so far is the [Greninja](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash%27s_Greninja).

True that by now we can believe that Pikachu and Ash have maximum trust, one of the requirements for the [Bond phenomena](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bond_Phenomenon) to happen.

But that might not be the only requirement, or Pikachu species does not have this bond ability.

It remains to be shown further if other pokemon than Greninja have that ability or not.

Comment: If you were talking in game terms, then it's not just an ability, it's an Ability - i.e. something specific to an individual Pokemon, and only one particular Greninja (the one that appears in the Sun Moon demo) has the "Battle Bond" Ability.

Comment: @ConMan yes. And the TCG card specifically states Ash's Greninja